# English Pronunciation Easter Eggs

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

I have been wondering recently if there are any Pronunciation "Easter Eggs" in the English language (not unlike how "Ghoti" is pronounced like "Fish"). Are there any others? Please provide phonetic proof if you claim so.

Comment: Ghoti was **created** to show the peculiarities of the English language... it didn't exist as a word on its own.

Comment: Ghoti isn't a real word.  It's just a written form of the word *fish* that is used to show the oddities of English pronunciation.  (where *gh* is /f/ via words like *cough*, *o* is /ɪ/ via *women*, and *ti* is /ʃ/ via words like those that end in *-tion*)

Comment: But what on earth has it all to do with Easter eggs?

Comment: @WS2: The people who programmed the English language obviously left some surprises in their code for us to find.

Comment: "ghoti", as mentioned earlier, doesn't exist as a real word, and it would be more likely to be pronounced "goaty," not "fish," if it did.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are potentially more fictitious "joke pronunciation words" (as *ghoti*) than there are "real" words in the English language - which must make this one of the most extreme "list type" questions ever posted here.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for real english words whose pronunciation is nothing like the one-to-one canonical pronunciation of individual letters? How about 'though' or 'hiccough' (apart from their initial letters).

Comment: Or Worcester? (woosta) Or Featherstonehaugh? (fanshaw) Though extreme, compared to other languages, English is almost all these 'made up' pronunciations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ghoti would not be considered an "Easter egg" word. It was made up to make a point about English pronunciation.

Regarding specifically "Easter eggs" within the language itself, none are widely documented, if they do exist. I've never heard/read of one, before.

When looking for them, take into consideration the risk of confirmation bias in regards to apophenia.

Comment: I've closevoted against the question itself, so I wouldn't normally upvote an *answer*. But new-to-me ***apophenia*** is just too good a word to pass by! :)

Comment: I learned about it at the following link. I've found the lesson in its entirety to be very helpful in many regards. I picked it up on Audible for cheap. They have a token system to circumvent some ridiculous pricing. http://www.thegreatcourses.com/courses/your-deceptive-mind-a-scientific-guide-to-critical-thinking-skills.html